# I want to pass reference of a vector to a function then modify it there and return as vector

Tags: function, vector, reference, rust, borrowing

I want to pass address of a vector that contains `i64` values to a function as argument, then I want my function to modify the vector at its original location and return the modified vector as `i64`.

I tried to pass mutable reference of the vector to the function and tried to modified it but compiler showing error: a struct with a similar name exists and error: expected type found macro etc.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut my_vector: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();
    my_vector.push(11);
    my_vector.push(12);
    my_vector.push(13);
    println!("{:?}", my_vector);
    let vec_ref: &[vec<i64>] = &my_vector;
    let v2 = change_vector(&mut vec_ref);
    println!("{:?}", v2);
    println!("{:?}", my_vector);
}

fn change_vector(new_vector: &[vec<i64>]) -> Vec<i64> {
    new_vector.push(11);
    new_vector
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4f219c3f711d35a57824ff471894f687))

I expect my function `change_vector()` to receive reference of the location of `my_vector`, modify it and then return it as vector. Its not happening, compiler showing errors and aborting:

```
error[E0573]: expected type, found macro `vec`
 --> src/main.rs:7:20
  |
7 |     let vec_ref: &[vec<i64>] = &my_vector;
  |                    ^^^^^^^^
help: a struct with a similar name exists
  |
7 |     let vec_ref: &[Vec<i64>] = &my_vector;
  |                    ^^^
help: use `!` to invoke the macro
  |
7 |     let vec_ref: &[vec!] = &my_vector;
  |                    ^^^^

error[E0573]: expected type, found macro `vec`
  --> src/main.rs:13:32
   |
13 | fn change_vector(new_vector: &[vec<i64>]) -> Vec<i64> {
   |                                ^^^^^^^^
help: a struct with a similar name exists
   |
13 | fn change_vector(new_vector: &[Vec<i64>]) -> Vec<i64> {
   |                                ^^^
help: use `!` to invoke the macro
   |
13 | fn change_vector(new_vector: &[vec!]) -> Vec<i64> {
   |                                ^^^^
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Why do you want to return it if it's the same vector ? Why not just [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a84ce230c3cdb44d00b363952fa4eeae) ?

Comment: Hi there! The cause of the error messages is a typo: you wrote `vec` but should have written `Vec` (uppercase). It really makes sense to completely read the error message, as this already suggests exactly this. I would propose to close this question since "fix the typo" isn't really a useful answer. But with the typo fixed, your code still does not compile. I'd ask you to create another question with the typo fixed -- then we can answer the new one easily! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues with your code stemming from incorrect syntax and goals. Let's go through them one by one:

```
let mut my_vector: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();
my_vector.push(11);
my_vector.push(12);
my_vector.push(13);
println!("{:?}", my_vector);
```

This is fine. `my_vector` contains `[11, 12, 13]`.

```
let vec_ref: &[vec<i64>] = &my_vector;
```

This is not fine. A reference to `Vec<i64>` is `&Vec<i64>`, not a slice. Change this to `let vec_ref:&Vec<i64> = &my_vector;`. You also do not need this line and if you decide to use this reference later, your code will stop compiling due to a later decision, which we are about to get to...

```
let v2 = change_vector(&mut vec_ref);
```

This is not fine. You cannot take a mutable reference of an immutable reference. It stands to reason.
`change_vector(&mut my_vector)` is fine syntactically, but combined with the previous assignment, is a minefield. You've acquired an immutable reference as `vec_ref` on the line above; if you do not use `vec_ref` the compiler will drop it entirely for you; however, if you do decide to use it your code will not compile due to you not being able to hold an immutable *and* a mutable borrow at the same time.

```
fn change_vector(new_vector: &[vec<i64>]) -> Vec<i64> {
```

This is not fine, for reasons above. It should be `fn change_vector(new_vector: &mut Vec<i64>) {`.

The reason the return type changed is that you cannot return an owned `Vec` from a reference without allocation. If you did want to allocate, then obviously this should be different.

```
new_vector.push(11);
```

This is fine.

```
new_vec
```

With the new return signature, this line is superfluous.

The corrected code is visible [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=406a4b75d5baa29bd02240b7dbe18dba)

Comment: My code had bugs other than typo which you and others correctly pointed out. Thank you so much for the rectification part. It was a big favor. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Anytime! I guess you're coming from C/C++ from the mistakes you made; don't hesitate to ask more stuff, I'm sure others and I will be happy to help you out

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the Vector by value, modify it and then return it:

```
fn change_vector(mut new_vector: Vec<i64>) -> Vec<i64> {
    new_vector.push(11);
    new_vector
}
```

This does not copy the contents of the vector, it just does a move (only copies the internal pointer of the vector and it's length)

Another possibility would taking the vector as mutable reference:

```
fn change_vector(new_vector: &mut Vec<i64>) {
    new_vector.push(11);
}
```

Your code (With capitalized Vec)

```
fn change_vector(new_vector: &[Vec<i64>]) -> Vec<i64> {
    new_vector.push(11);
    new_vector
}
```

accepts a slice of vectors of i64, which is probably not what you want